# Javascript array changes after function without being involved

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm confused. I have an array `myArray = [2, 2, 2, 1, 1]` and without knowing, it takes the values of the Array testArray.

```
if(count == 5) {
    alert("beginn" + myArray[2]);
    var testArray=testFunction(myArray);
    alert("middle" + myArray[2]);
    var testCount=countNumber(testArray);
    if (testCount = 3){
        count = 4;
    }
}
```

And here is the function:

```
function testFunction(testArray){
    var minimum=Math.min.apply(Math,testArray);
    var i=0;
    var position=-1;
    for(i;i<testArray.length;i++){
        if(position==-1){
            if(minimum==testArray[i]){
                position=i;
            }
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    for(i; i < testArray.length; i++){
        if(i != position){
            testArray[i] = testArray[i] - 1;
        }
    }

    return testArray;
}
```

So after the function testArray is correctly `[1,1,1,1,0]`, but unfortunately also myArray and I don't know why.

Comment: Please stop using those horrible german function names. Not only are they not english, they are also WAY too verbose. (I'm german myself, so it's not "some stupid american" complaining ;))

Comment: This happens because arrays in javascript are passed [by reference](http://orizens.com/wp/topics/javascript-arrays-passing-by-reference-or-by-value/), if you want to pass them by value, use `var testArray = testFunction(myArray.slice());`, also, indent your code. (=

Comment: Aren't arrays passed by reference in javascript? That would mean you're returning an array here, but also modifying the original since that's what you're referring to from within your function.

Comment: Don't you mean to say `if (testCount == 3)`

Comment: also watchout for that 'if(testCount=3)': you are assigning value 3 to testCount var, not checking its value

Comment: @TehSoTo - Well, technically nothing in JavaScript is passed by reference.  However, the address to that array is passed... by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, when you assign an array object to another variable you are basically assigning a pointer to the original array object. This means that if you do this:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4];
var testArray = myArray;
```

then any changes made to testArray will also be made to myArray because they are actually the same array!

To keep `myArray` from changing, you would need to pass a copy of the array:

```
var myCopy = myArray.slice(0);
var testArray=testFunction(myCopy);
```